# Remote host closed connection during handshake - Certificate issue or connectivity?

Tags: linux, ssl, curl

I am getting SSL Handshake Exception when trying to communicate with a server.
I tried doing a curl to the server to figure out if there is connectivity but got the below error.

**NSS error -5938 (PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR)**

Please check the screenshots for the SSL handshake error.
[image]

Also the error when doing curl:

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/543481/419782) and other answers to the same question

Comment: Is the SSL service in the remote machine working? How did you verify?  I am guessing the service is throwing some errors. I would test with openssl: `openssl s_client -connect IP:PORT`